# How to subtract timestamp of 2 different custom metric with same value in datadog

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I want to create a metric **Callback_welcomed** and **callback_recieved** for both of them I want to put the callback id as the value.
Then subtract timestamp of metric2 from metric1 for same value, to get trends for callbackwait time.

Comment: Very easy to do on a dashboard. Add your two metrics, then add a formula to subtract. https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/querying/#metric-arithmetic-using-an-integer